# Ubuntu 18.04 alt-tab order is weird when on multiple screens -- any way to adjust?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, window-manager, application-switcher

Before the upgrade I was using 14.04 and I was happy with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> behavior for switching between apps and between windows of an app respectively. Both showed me the items in last recently used order, in particular single <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> always switched me to the previous one.

Now, in 18.04, I can't help understanding what order it offers to me. It looks like it's not last-recently-used any more. Sometimes <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> switches me to the window already active. Sometimes to get to the previously active window I have to do <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>. Is there any way to restore the intuitive behavior?

Also, an annoying thing is, if I switch to one window of an application, the whole application is brought up. Any way to disable this?

Comment: no, it's about the order, not about apps vs windows

Comment: Alexey, I feel I'm experiencing the same problem. I find the window switching very frustrating, and I am wondering if you ever figured this out?

Answer (score 0):

The GNOME Shell's default setting for Alt+Tab in 18.04 is to switch applications, rather than windows. To change to a window-centric switching behavior, you can access the Keyboard settings app and change the "Switch windows" function to Alt+Tab. You will need to acknowledge that you are removing the current mapping for "Switch applications."

[This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNQ75OMAw7M) has a more thorough explanation of the setting change.